# Laravel 4.2 log files not being created

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-4.2

After resolving an error that was causing my log files to explode (2+ GB log files all full of the same exception log), I deleted the affected log files to avoid having it eat up unnecessary space. This was an error that was a couple of days old, and it affected multiple log files.

Since deleting the log files, however, it looks as if laravel has stopped logging anything. The daily log for the day I made the deletion seems to have stopped logging at the moment I deleted the older daily files, and no new daily files have been created since.

I've rerun composer install, artisan dump-autoload, artisan clear-compiled, and artisan cache:clear, to no avail. The permission settings all look fine as near as I can tell, and are assigned to the correct user. There were no configuration changes made at all, literally the only difference was in deleting the old daily log files.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with this? Can provide more information as necessary if I'm missing anything relevant.

Comment: The obvious suspect is file permission. Have you look at your php error log? Can laravel write into your log dir? Just try a `file_put_contents('/path/to/log/dir/debug', 'test');` from a controller and see if it works

Comment: This actually worked, so I tried adding a Log::debug('test') call to an artisan command, and that successfully created a log file. This is very unusual, there's gotta be a breakdown somewhere else in our logging, there's usually a steady stream of logged behavior in the file.

Comment: Notice that apache or whatever your webserver is might NOT have the same permission as your user running the artisan command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't a logging error at all; turns out the problem was my cron scheduler got disabled and key processes weren't running. Different problem to solve, but glad to know I didn't break logging.